# R: {modeltime}'s ts_split_indices object appears not to qualify as an rsplit object

Tags: r, time-series, tidymodels

In the below reprex I believe I followed the example from https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/08/introducing-iterative-nested-forecasting-with-modeltime/ exactly. However, I get an error when trying to extract the training data from the split object saying that the `ts_split_indices` object needs to be an `rsplit` object. Does anyone know why this might be the case?

Thank you in advance.

```r
library(tidymodels)
library(modeltime)
library(tidyverse)
library(timetk)

data_tbl <- walmart_sales_weekly %>%
  select(id, Date, Weekly_Sales) %>%
  set_names(c("id", "date", "value"))

data_tbl
#> # A tibble: 1,001 × 3
#>    id    date        value
#>    <fct> <date>      <dbl>
#>  1 1_1   2010-02-05 24924.
#>  2 1_1   2010-02-12 46039.
#>  3 1_1   2010-02-19 41596.
#>  4 1_1   2010-02-26 19404.
#>  5 1_1   2010-03-05 21828.
#>  6 1_1   2010-03-12 21043.
#>  7 1_1   2010-03-19 22137.
#>  8 1_1   2010-03-26 26229.
#>  9 1_1   2010-04-02 57258.
#> 10 1_1   2010-04-09 42961.
#> # … with 991 more rows

data_tbl %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  plot_time_series(
    date, value, .interactive = F, .facet_ncol = 2
  )
```

[image]

```r
nested_data_tbl <- data_tbl %>%
  
  # 1. Extending: We'll predict 52 weeks into the future.
  extend_timeseries(
    .id_var        = id,
    .date_var      = date,
    .length_future = 52
  ) %>%
  
  # 2. Nesting: We'll group by id, and create a future dataset
  #    that forecasts 52 weeks of extended data and
  #    an actual dataset that contains 104 weeks (2-years of data)
  nest_timeseries(
    .id_var        = id,
    .length_future = 52,
    .length_actual = 52*2
  ) %>%
  
  # 3. Splitting: We'll take the actual data and create splits
  #    for accuracy and confidence interval estimation of 52 weeks (test)
  #    and the rest is training data
  split_nested_timeseries(
    .length_test = 52
  )

nested_data_tbl
#> # A tibble: 7 × 4
#>   id    .actual_data       .future_data      .splits        
#>   <fct> <list>             <list>            <list>         
#> 1 1_1   <tibble [104 × 2]> <tibble [52 × 2]> <split [52|52]>
#> 2 1_3   <tibble [104 × 2]> <tibble [52 × 2]> <split [52|52]>
#> 3 1_8   <tibble [104 × 2]> <tibble [52 × 2]> <split [52|52]>
#> 4 1_13  <tibble [104 × 2]> <tibble [52 × 2]> <split [52|52]>
#> 5 1_38  <tibble [104 × 2]> <tibble [52 × 2]> <split [52|52]>
#> 6 1_93  <tibble [104 × 2]> <tibble [52 × 2]> <split [52|52]>
#> 7 1_95  <tibble [104 × 2]> <tibble [52 × 2]> <split [52|52]>

rec_prophet <- recipe(value ~ date, training(nested_data_tbl$.splits[[1]]))
#> Error in `analysis()`:
#> ! `x` should be an `rsplit` object

#> Backtrace:
#>     ▆
#>  1. ├─recipes::recipe(value ~ date, training(nested_data_tbl$.splits[[1]]))
#>  2. ├─recipes:::recipe.formula(value ~ date, training(nested_data_tbl$.splits[[1]]))
#>  3. │ └─recipes:::form2args(formula, data, ...)
#>  4. │   └─tibble::is_tibble(data)
#>  5. └─rsample::training(nested_data_tbl$.splits[[1]])
#>  6.   └─rsample::analysis(x)
#>  7.     └─rlang::abort("`x` should be an `rsplit` object")

class(nested_data_tbl$.splits[[1]])
#> [1] "ts_split_indicies"
training(nested_data_tbl$.splits[[1]])
#> Error in `analysis()`:
#> ! `x` should be an `rsplit` object

#> Backtrace:
#>     ▆
#>  1. └─rsample::training(nested_data_tbl$.splits[[1]])
#>  2.   └─rsample::analysis(x)
#>  3.     └─rlang::abort("`x` should be an `rsplit` object")
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
#>  os       PureOS
#>  system   x86_64, linux-gnu
#>  ui       X11
#>  language (EN)
#>  collate  en_US.UTF-8
#>  ctype    en_US.UTF-8
#>  tz       America/New_York
#>  date     2022-11-29
#>  pandoc   2.19.2 @ /usr/lib/rstudio/bin/quarto/bin/tools/ (via rmarkdown)
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package       * version    date (UTC) lib source
#>  assertthat      0.2.1      2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  backports       1.4.1      2021-12-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  broom         * 1.0.1      2022-08-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  cellranger      1.1.0      2016-07-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  class           7.3-19     2021-05-03 [4] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  cli             3.4.1      2022-09-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  codetools       0.2-18     2020-11-04 [4] CRAN (R 4.0.4)
#>  colorspace      2.0-3      2022-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  crayon          1.5.2      2022-09-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  curl            4.3.3      2022-10-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  DBI             1.1.3      2022-06-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  dbplyr          2.2.1      2022-06-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  dials         * 1.1.0      2022-11-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  DiceDesign      1.9        2021-02-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  digest          0.6.30     2022-10-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  dplyr         * 1.0.10     2022-09-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  ellipsis        0.3.2      2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  evaluate        0.18       2022-11-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  fansi           1.0.3      2022-03-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  farver          2.1.1      2022-07-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  fastmap         1.1.0      2021-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  forcats       * 0.5.2      2022-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  foreach         1.5.2      2022-02-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  fs              1.5.2      2021-12-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  furrr           0.3.1      2022-08-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  future          1.29.0     2022-11-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  future.apply    1.10.0     2022-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  gargle          1.2.1      2022-09-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  generics        0.1.3      2022-07-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  ggplot2       * 3.4.0      2022-11-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  globals         0.16.2     2022-11-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  glue            1.6.2      2022-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  googledrive     2.0.0      2021-07-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  googlesheets4   1.0.1      2022-08-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  gower           1.0.0      2022-02-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  GPfit           1.0-8      2019-02-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  gtable          0.3.1      2022-09-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  hardhat         1.2.0      2022-06-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  haven           2.5.1      2022-08-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  highr           0.9        2021-04-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  hms             1.1.2      2022-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  htmltools       0.5.3      2022-07-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  httr            1.4.4      2022-08-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  infer         * 1.0.3      2022-08-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  ipred           0.9-13     2022-06-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  iterators       1.0.14     2022-02-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  jsonlite        1.8.3      2022-10-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  knitr           1.41       2022-11-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  labeling        0.4.2      2020-10-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  lattice         0.20-45    2021-09-22 [4] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  lava            1.7.0      2022-10-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  lhs             1.1.5      2022-03-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  lifecycle       1.0.3      2022-10-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  listenv         0.8.0      2019-12-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  lubridate       1.9.0      2022-11-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  magrittr        2.0.3      2022-03-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  MASS            7.3-58.1   2022-08-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  Matrix          1.5-3      2022-11-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  mime            0.12       2021-09-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  modeldata     * 1.0.1      2022-09-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  modelr          0.1.10     2022-11-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  modeltime     * 1.2.4      2022-11-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  munsell         0.5.0      2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  nnet            7.3-16     2021-05-03 [4] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  parallelly      1.32.1     2022-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  parsnip       * 1.0.3      2022-11-24 [1] Github (tidymodels/parsnip@c2cb86d)
#>  pillar          1.8.1      2022-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  pkgconfig       2.0.3      2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  prodlim         2019.11.13 2019-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  purrr         * 0.3.5      2022-10-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  R.cache         0.16.0     2022-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  R.methodsS3     1.8.2      2022-06-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  R.oo            1.25.0     2022-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  R.utils         2.12.2     2022-11-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  R6              2.5.1      2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  Rcpp            1.0.9      2022-07-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  RcppParallel    5.1.5      2022-01-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  readr         * 2.1.3      2022-10-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  readxl          1.4.1      2022-08-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  recipes       * 1.0.3      2022-11-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  reprex          2.0.2      2022-08-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  rlang           1.0.6      2022-09-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  rmarkdown       2.18       2022-11-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  rpart           4.1-15     2019-04-12 [4] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  rsample       * 1.1.0      2022-08-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  rstudioapi      0.14       2022-08-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  rvest           1.0.3      2022-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  scales        * 1.2.1      2022-08-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  sessioninfo     1.2.2      2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  StanHeaders     2.21.0-7   2020-12-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  stringi         1.7.8      2022-07-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  stringr       * 1.4.1      2022-08-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  styler          1.8.1      2022-11-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  survival        3.2-13     2021-08-24 [4] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  tibble        * 3.1.8      2022-07-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  tidymodels    * 1.0.0      2022-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  tidyr         * 1.2.1      2022-09-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  tidyselect      1.2.0      2022-10-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  tidyverse     * 1.3.2      2022-07-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  timechange      0.1.1      2022-11-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  timeDate        4021.106   2022-09-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  timetk        * 2.8.2      2022-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  tune          * 1.0.1      2022-10-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  tzdb            0.3.0      2022-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  utf8            1.2.2      2021-07-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  vctrs           0.5.1      2022-11-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  withr           2.5.0      2022-03-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  workflows     * 1.1.2      2022-11-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  workflowsets  * 1.0.0      2022-07-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  xfun            0.35       2022-11-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  xml2            1.3.3      2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  xts             0.12.2     2022-10-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  yaml            2.3.6      2022-10-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  yardstick     * 1.1.0      2022-09-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  zoo             1.8-11     2022-09-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#> 
#>  [1] /home/arcenisrojas/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1
#>  [2] /usr/local/lib/R/site-library
#>  [3] /usr/lib/R/site-library
#>  [4] /usr/lib/R/library
#> 
#> ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the solution to my question is the `extract_nested_train_split()` function. I.e, rather than using `training(nested_data_tbl$.splits[[1]])`, I would just use `extract_nested_train_split(nested_data_tbl)`